# Adding Google Recaptcha to ASP.NET Form - error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: c#, asp.net, recaptcha

I'm attempting to add Google Recaptcha to my form, but I currently get the following error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 173.194.----

Please see the following:
**Client-side**:

```
<recaptcha:recaptchacontrol id="RecaptchaControl2" runat="server" publickey="888" privatekey="777" theme="blackglass"></recaptcha:recaptchacontrol>

<asp:button runat="server" id="btnSendFeedback" 
                        Text="Submit" onclick="btnSendFeedback_Click" />

<p><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblResult" /></p>
```

Server-side:

```
protected void btnSendFeedback_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            lblResult.Text = "Correct!";
            //lblResult.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            sendEmail();
        }
        else
        {
            lblResult.Text = "Incorrect";
            //lblResult.ForeColor = Color.Red;

        }
    }
```

...The sendEmail(); function is just to typical code to email a form. Could I get some assistance as to what I', doing wrong? The form work well when I remove the captcha related code. However, when Implenmented, I get the following error:  No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Comment: Firewall blocking google's IP address ?

Comment: Thanks, that is actually what the issue was.